# How do I handle server push within ExtJS 4.2.2 app?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Getting started investigating server push to ExtJS apps, but I have a question about how to handle it on the ExtJS side.

My understanding is that with server push, ExtJS app might have no idea the server might push to it.

Is this the case, or do I need to do something to make my ExtJS app "server push aware", like making it listen or ready to get the pushed data?

I imagine server pushing some data, and ExtJS just gets it and handles the data.

But how does the server know where to push the data to? If there are 5 types of server push that at any time might go to an ExtJS app, how does the server know where each of those 5 pushes go to?

Sorry if I seem ignorant of how all this works, but I'm just getting started in this and am wondering how this stuff works with ExtJS.

Comment: I didnt understand completely but i think you are looking for 'websockets'.Here is something related : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261699

Comment: That helps a little, but what I'm really looking for is a very basic description of how an ExtJS app is going to handle the pushed data. How does the server know where to send the data, and how does the ExtJS app get the message? I'm assuming others new to push, and ExtJS, might benefit from this.

Comment: Server can send data to queues probably and using websockets Extjs app can subscribe to the particular queue.Whenever data is being pushed in the queue,you will be getting data to the data in the form of messages to client side.

Comment: Take a look at Frozen Mountain [Websync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/products/websync)